# XSSFWorkbook Apache POI No libera memoria

Tags: java, apache-poi

Leo un excel `*.xls` de unos 10 megas, en el siguiente paso se incrementa el proceso `javaw.exe` en 1.5 Gb.

```
public void importExcelMedidas(FileBean fBean) throws IOException {
    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(fichero.getBytes());
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input); //<- Incrementa 1,5gb

    input.close();
    workbook.close();
    input = null;
    workbook=null;
    fBean=null;
    System.gc();
    System.out.println("FIN"); <- Depurando, aqui sigue con el mismo consumo.
}
```

Después cierro el `input.close();`, `workbook.close()` y ejecuto `System.gc();`.

Pero al mirar el proceso `javaw.exe` continúa con el mismo tamaño.

¿Cómo puedo liberar la memoria?

PD: También he cerrado conexiones y asignado a null.

Comment: Solo intente reemplazar `XSSFWorkbook` con [SXSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html). está diseñado para vaciar filas en el disco en lugar de mantenerlas en la memoria. > Vea la descripción en: > - http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html y - > - http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf --- Vea aquí una información interesante sobre unas preguntas de SO: - [¿Los POI XSSF todavía tienen problemas de mala memoria?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30186911/8933039) (Traducir del Inglés). - [Procesamiento de un archivo xlsx grande](

Comment: Ya había visto ese problema, pero para mi no es problema el consumo de memoria, sino que no libere la memoria al finalizar el proceso.

Comment: pero igual, el **Consumo de memoria es un problema** y debe evitarlo...

Comment: `fichero` en que parte se define?

Comment: por cierto, por que no usas algo como `fBean.getInputStream()`?

Answer (score 0):

Como te lo dice J. Rodríguez es la forma como hacerlo pero quiero dejarte un ejemplo como utilizarla.

Ahí puedes definir que cuando termine de leer la ultima fila vacie la memoria

> El siguiente ejemplo escribe una hoja con una ventana de 100 filas. Cuando el recuento de filas alcanza 101, la fila con rownum = 0 se vacía en el disco y se elimina de la memoria, cuando rownum llega a 102, la fila con rownum = 1 se vacía, etc.

```
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100); // keep 100 rows in memory, exceeding rows will be flushed to disk
    Sheet sh = wb.createSheet();
    for(int rownum = 0; rownum < 1000; rownum++){
        Row row = sh.createRow(rownum);
        for(int cellnum = 0; cellnum < 10; cellnum++){
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum);
            String address = new CellReference(cell).formatAsString();
            cell.setCellValue(address);
        }

    }

    // Rows with rownum < 900 are flushed and not accessible
    for(int rownum = 0; rownum < 900; rownum++){
      Assert.assertNull(sh.getRow(rownum));
    }

    // ther last 100 rows are still in memory
    for(int rownum = 900; rownum < 1000; rownum++){
        Assert.assertNotNull(sh.getRow(rownum));
    }

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/temp/sxssf.xlsx");
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();

    // dispose of temporary files backing this workbook on disk
    wb.dispose();
}
```

En este link que te dejo puedes ver mas ejemplos y se explica más [poi](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf)

**Este el concept de la función:**

`SXSSF (paquete: org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming)` es una extensión de transmisión de `XSSF` compatible con `API` que se utilizará cuando se deben producir hojas de cálculo muy grandes, y el espacio de almacenamiento dinámico es limitado. SXSSF logra su huella de memoria baja al limitar el acceso a las filas que se encuentran dentro de una ventana deslizante, mientras que XSSF da acceso a todas las filas del documento. Las filas antiguas que ya no se encuentran en la ventana se vuelven inaccesibles, ya que se escriben en el disco.

Comment: Yo leo el excel, no lo escribo.

Comment: Para entender mejor lo que haces puedes editar la pregunta y mostrar todo el código de como trabajas el excel

Comment: Ya he añadido el codigo, ahora mismo lo tengo asi, y no libera la memoria. ¿SXSSF sirve para leer también?

Comment: @nachfren prueba de esta manera `Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("yourfile.xlsx"));`

Comment: Ya he probado así, y ocurre lo mismo cuando se crea el `Workbook` aumeta el tamaño del proceso, y al finalizar no lo libera.

Answer (score 0):

Si crees que tienes inconvenientes al llamar el método de cerrado sobre los archivos puedes intentar usar una instancia de [`NPOIFSFileSystem`](https://NPOIFSFileSystempoi.apache.org/apidocs/3.17/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/NPOIFSFileSystem.html#:%7E:text=This%20is%20the%20main%20class,version%2C%20which%20uses%20less%20memory).

```
InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(fichero.getBytes());
NPOIFSFileSystem npoifs = null;
npoifs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(input);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input)
```